# Why can't I resize NTFS partition?

Tags: 13.10, partitioning, ntfs, ntfs-3g

I'm trying to resize my ntfs partition but can't do it in GParted... tried from HD and from LiveUSB... couldn't find a solution on the web, partition isn't mounted; I'm trying to divide it in two to install another Ubuntu version.

I used Ubuntu 13.10 in both installed on HD and LiveUSB.

*ntfs-3g* is installed; *ntfsprogs* can't be installed.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The filesystem is apparently fubar ( fouled up beyond all recognition ).  Try  booting into windows and running chkdsk on it.

Comment: and always provide the operating system in use.

Comment: @Rinzwind, since this is askubuntu, there is no need for that; it is assumed the OS is Ubuntu.

Comment: You already have used all 4 primary partitions, so you have to also do some reorganization also. You have to then create new partitions inside the extended and moved data/partitions around so unallocated is inside extended.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @psusi said I couldn't edit the partition because CHDISK was scheduled to run... then I just entered Windows and waited for it to finish, then partition was able to be resized by GParted.

Then did reorganization as @oldfred stated.

Package *ntfs-3g* substitutes *ntfsprogs* (which is an old package)

Thank you for the help!!

**EDIT**: I don't have Windows installed anymore and the general recommendation from the open source community is that you should not use Windows or any closed-source software. Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem today when I tried to resize the partition(ntfs) for Windows. I tried with 'other modes'-->'removal later' mode to enter Gparted, and there was no this problem. I don't know why, but you may try.
ps: my Gparted is Gparted-live.